# How to pass one query result to another?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Hi guys, Don't focus on the title of question my main question is this. I am bit confused what exactly I should ask.**

Define an SQL view Q1(courseid, code) that gives the distinct course id and subject code of any course that is taught by course Tutor (refers to the staff_roles.name). We only consider the courses with the subject code starting with ‘LAWS’, like ‘LAWS1213’. The view should return the following details about each course:

•   Courseid should be taken from courses. id field.

•   Code should be taken from subjects. Code field.

My Table structures as are as follows.

```
create table Courses (
    id          integer, -- PG: serial
    subject     integer not null references Subjects(id),
    semester    integer not null references Semesters(id),
    homepage    URLString,
    primary key (id)
);

create table Subjects (
    id          integer, -- PG: serial
    code        char(8) not null,
--                PG: check (code ~ '[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}'),
    name        MediumName not null 
);

create table Course_staff (
    course      integer references Courses(id),
    staff       integer references Staff(id),
    role        integer references Staff_roles(id),
    primary key (course,staff,role)
);

create table Staff_roles (
    id          integer, -- PG: serial
    rtype       char(1) references Staff_role_types(id),
    rclass      char(1) references Staff_role_classes(id),
    name        LongString not null,
    description LongString,
    primary key (id)
);
```

**Kindly tell me the query. What query I should write.**

**I tried this but no luck.**

```
select Courses.id
     , Subjects.code 
  from Courses
     , Subjects
     , Staff_roles 
 where ( Courses.subject = Subjects.id 
     AND Subjects.code like 'LAWS%' 
     AND Staff_roles.name ='Course Tutor'
       );
```

Comment: At this point. I think 20 minutes spent in the company of any basic introductory book or tutorial would be time well spent.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: What is the use of staff details here ?